# How to test the significant difference between two correlation coefficients?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance

Suppose I have three variables, $X, Y, Z$. And I am interested in knowing how $X, Z$ are correlated to $Y$. Suppose that $$
corr(Y, X) = a=0.6; \quad \text{and} \quad corr(Y, Z) = b=0.4;
$$
My question is, is there a way to test the whether the two correlation coefficients are significantly different? Or am I going to the wrong direction when doing this?

Comment: Duplicate of:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114001/how-to-test-for-a-significant-difference-between-several-dependent-correlation-c

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cocor/cocor.pdf) is an R package that examines the difference between correlation coefficients for dependent or independent groups.

The specific function is given below:

```
cocor(formula, data, alternative = "two.sided", test = "all",
na.action = getOption("na.action"), alpha = 0.05, conf.level = 0.95,
null.value = 0, return.htest = FALSE)
```

This package is based on the following [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18179351) by GY Zou entitled *Toward using confidence intervals to compare correlations*.

In the example in the R package, the dataset  `aptitude`  is used:

```
 # Compare two correlations based on two depenendent groups
 # The correlations are overlapping

 cocor(~knowledge + intelligence.a | logic + intelligence.a, aptitude$sample1)
 cocor(~knowledge + intelligence.a | logic + intelligence.a, aptitude$sample2)
```

This code performs a significance test to examine whether $\text{corr}(\text{knowledge}, \text{intelligence})$ and $\text{corr}(\text{logic}, \text{intelligence})$ are significantly different. Note that the shared variable is  `intelligence` . The  `sample1`  and  `sample2`  are the two dependent groups.

Comment: Could you please explain what it does or how it works, as well as what input it expects and what assumptions it makes about that input?